# Set Date by day of week, week & year

Tags: javascript, date

I'm building a calendar. I have events on the calendar that repeat yearly on the same day of week.

For example:

- eventOne, Sunday (0), Week 3
- eventTwo, Tuesday (2), week 12

EventOne should have a date object that is always the  Sunday for week 3 of the current year.

EventTwo should have a date object that is always the Tuesday of week 12 of the current year.

```js
function getDateOfISOWeek(w, y) {
  var simple = new Date(y, 0, 1 + (w - 1) * 7)
  var dow = simple.getDay()
  var ISOweekStart = simple
  if (dow <= 4)
    ISOweekStart.setDate(simple.getDate() - simple.getDay() + 1)
  else
    ISOweekStart.setDate(simple.getDate() + 8 - simple.getDay())
  return ISOweekStart
}

const date = getDateOfISOWeek(3, 2020)
console.log(date)
```

The above function will give me the first day of the week I'm requesting but no implementation for the day of week and I've struggled to find a Date function todo this.

I'm happy to use moment or date-fns if there are any convenience functions to help out, but would prefer if I could get to a native javascript solution.

Comment: Your date is the timezone regulated start of week. I see Sunday 12th of Jan at 23:00 - what is your problem exactly?

Comment: btw jan 12 is the second sunday and not the third as you are looking for

Comment: So the "Sunday of the 3rd week of January" is a fixed thing or you want to be able to change that?

Comment: If thrid week is a fixed thing then why do you want to pass in the week parameter to you getDateISOWeek?

Comment: Okay so say I wanted the date to be consistently on week 3, wednesday, theres no accounting for the day of week I'd like to adjust it to.

Comment: I am sorry, I have no idea what you are asking

Comment: @mplungjan I've updated the description - does that make more sense? Apologies it's tricky to expand on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm not sure, but if i understand correctly you could make this simply using date-fns:

```
var startOfYear = require('date-fns/start_of_year')
var getDay = require('date-fns/get_day')
var addDays = require('date-fns/add_days')
var addWeeks = require('date-fns/add_weeks')    

let getDateOfISOWeek = (w, y, d) => {
  let startDayOfYear = startOfYear(new Date(y,0,1));
  let diff = d - getDay(startDayOfYear);
  let firstAppearanceOfYear = addDays(startDayOfYear, diff < 0 ? 7 + diff : diff);
  return addWeeks(firstAppearanceOfYear, w - 1);
}

let result = getDateOfISOWeek(3, 2020, 0); //Sun Jan 19 2020
let result2 = getDateOfISOWeek(3, 2021, 0); // Sun Jan 17 2021
```

first two arguments - week & year, third - index of day you are looking for(0 - Sunday, 6 - Saturday)

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was trying to achieve! Very grateful thank you.

I made some minor amends around let to const and adding year via; const year = new Date(y, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)

Comment: This returns incorrect results. ISO week 3 of 2020 started on Mon 13 Jan 2020. ECMAScript day 3 is Wednesday, so the result for week 3 of 2020 day 3 should be Wed 15 Jan, not Sun 19 Jan. 3,2021, 3 should be Wed 20 Jan, not Sun 17.

Comment: @RobG I am sorry, the code works correct as should, i just wrote wrong response

Comment: The second result is still wrong. Sunday in ISO week 3 of 2021 is 24 Jan, not 17 Jan (the first week starts on Mon 4 Jan 2021). The answer should not require a library not mentioned or tagged in the OP. The OP's getDateOfISOWeek works fine, a library isn't required.

Comment: @RobG can you check https://stackoverflow.com/a/59667261/295783 since I am not 100% sure it works on edge dates

Answer (score 2):

The *getDateOfISOWeek* works fine, though it's a little clunky. You just need to add the required number of days to get the particular day you want.

ISO weeks start on Monday, so it's just a matter of getting the start of the week and adding the day number less 1. Sunday can be 0 or 7 so either ECMAScript or ISO numbering is OK.

```js
/* Return date for start of ISO week in given year
** @param {number|string} week: required ISO week number
** @param {number|string} year: required year
** @returns {Date} date of Monday at start of week
*/
function getDateOfISOWeek(week, year) {
  // Get date for 1 Jan in given year
  let d = new Date(year, 0, 1);
  let dow = d.getDay();

  // Shift to start of ISO week 1
  d.setDate((dow <= 4? 2 : 9) - d.getDay());
  
  // Add required number of weeks
  d.setDate(d.getDate() + (week - 1)*7);
  
  return d;
}

/* Return date for a day in given ISO week in given year
** @param {number|string} day: day number, Mon=1, Tue=2, ... Sun=0 or 7
** @param {number|string} week: required ISO week number
** @param {number|string} year: required year
** @returns {Date} date of required day
*/
function getDayOfISOWeek(day, week, year) {
  let d = getDateOfISOWeek(week, year);
  d.setDate(d.getDate() + (+day || 7) - 1);
  return d;
}

// Options for formatting dates
let opts =  {weekday:'short', day:'numeric', month:'short', year:'numeric'};

// Examples
[[1, 3,2020], // Mon, week 3, 2020
 [0, 1,2020], // Sun, week 1, 2020
 [7, 1,2020], // Sun, week 1, 2020
 [5,10,2020], // Fri, week 10, 2020
 [6,27,2022], // Sat, week 27, 2022
 [2,12,2020], // Tue, week 12, 2020
 [2,12,2021], // Tue, week 12, 2021
 [2,12,2022]  // Tue, week 12, 2022
].forEach(args => console.log(
  args + ': ' + getDayOfISOWeek(...args).toLocaleString(void 0, opts)
));
```

PS. You really should include braces for blocks and semicolons to terminate statements, otherwise you can get some really difficult to find bugs.

Comment: Just wanted to comment that I don't agree on semicolons, but thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply implement a such function, by subtracting the offset from weeks times 7; and calculating the offset based on 4th January (because that's the day which is [always in the 1st week](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date))

Notes:

- If you consider Sunday as the first day of the week, pass 0 as `weekDay`, while if you consider Sunday as the last day of the week, you should pass 7.
- The `week` is one-based, passing `1` may result in a Date with the value of the previous year (e.g. `createDate(2020, 1, 1)` will return 30 December 2019.

```js
function createDate(year, week, weekDay){
  const date = new Date(year, 0, 4)
  const offset = (date.getDay() || 7) - weekDay
  date.setDate(week * 7 - offset - 3)
  return date
}

console.log(createDate(2020,3,7).toDateString())
console.log(createDate(2021,3,7).toDateString())
console.log(createDate(2020,12,4).toDateString())
console.log(createDate(2021,12,4).toDateString())
console.log(createDate(2015,1,4).toDateString())
```

Comment: I thought your code worked. But it does not. Sunday in the 3rd week of 2021 is not the 10th

Comment: That is not answering the issue. Your results are not the same in 2020 as in 2021 regardless

Comment: Jan 19 is in week 4 in 2020 and Jan 17 in 2021 is correctly week 3

Comment: @mplungjan My simple solution is finally back and it works now (verified against a calendar)! I've felt like I have to figure out what I've got wrong. Thank you for pointing out the issue!

Comment: console.log(createDate(2020,1,7).toDateString()) - is that what you would expect?

Comment: @mplungjan Yes, why? It returns 5th Jan, the Sunday of the 1st week...

Comment: It’s week 2 if I look. Last Sunday in December we s week 1

Comment: @mplungjan What kind of calendar do you use? In mine, if I set Monday as first, it gives that the first week is from Mon, 30th Dec - Sun, 5th Jan. If I set Sunday as first, it gives that the first week is from Sun, 29th Dec - Sat, 4th Jan; but in that case, `console.log(createDate(2020,1,0).toDateString())` (`0` instead of `7`) should be used instead, which correctly prints Sun 29th Dec; and `console.log(createDate(2020,2,0).toDateString())` prints Sun 5th Jan...

Comment: I see your point. I did not think we had a choice - but us/au  and others may consider Sunday the first day in a  week and then your code indeed can use 0 or 7

Comment: @mplungjan Then, is there any other problems with this code?

Comment: I guess not if the user takes care of the concerns I have

Comment: 4 Jan might always be *in* the first week, but it's only occasionally the *start* of the first week, so you can't base calculations on it being the start.

Comment: @RobG My code doesn't assume that 4th January is the start of the first week (4th Jan's `getDay()` value is subtracted from it, to find the first day of that week)

Comment: So the calculation is then essentially the same as using 1 Jan, though I guess a little simpler. I assumed ISO week numbering as the OP's function is called "getDateOfISOWeek". ;-)

Comment: @RobG This solution **does** use the ISO week numbering, I've just renamed my function, to show that it's something different than OP's try. Using 1st January as a base would be different, since 1st Jan can be both in the 1st and 53th week (you can see my wrong solution in the edit history)...

Comment: This fails for years where 1 Jan is a Thursday (e.g. 2015 and 2009), returning Monday in the first week as 5 Jan when it's 29 Dec the previous year. The problem is that the 4th is Sunday, so *getDay* returns 0 when it needs to be 7. Change to `let offset = (date.getDay() || 7) - weekDay;`.

Comment: @RobG That really was a problem. I've fixed it now, thanks for pointing out! And... I think I'll never answer any date-related questions again...